# aspectjweaver with Spring without aop.xml

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I am working on a project that uses aspectjweaver load-time weaving and spring. I read documentation and in all cases it was referred to `aop.xml` file located inside `/META-INF`. But in our case we do not have it and everything seems to work. We do have aspect declaration inside application context as spring beans.

When running application we specify path to javaagent aspectjweaver as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html)

Isn't is a requirement to have `aop.xml` inside resources? I got confused.